# Freeswitch/FusionPBX trying to list all inbound routes/destinations and their associated actions

Tags: voip, freeswitch

I mainly work with Asterisk/FreePBX but just recently started working with Freeswitch on a large scale so forgive me as I'm only now starting to explore a lot of the interface.

Issue: User wants to be able to see all inbound routes and associated targets/actions but can't for the life of me figure out how to easily display this. Currently, I need to enter into the destination to see where it's routing or go off the description (most of which are incorrect).

I'm going to look into putting together script for it, but for the sake of end-user self-service, let me know if you have any alternate solutions/modules that may help.